# Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight and XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8

Is there any way I can add XAML controls to my WP 8.1 Silverlight app? I'd like to use progress rings and toggle switches but it seems like Silverlight doesn't have them. How can I add them?

Adding a "using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls" reference doesn't work by the way.

Answer (score 4):

Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls is Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime only (or better known as Universal App).  If you don't like the controls already in Silverlight, Microsoft has release a extended control kit all "Windows Phone Toolkit".  You can get it using NuGet by right clicking the References -> Manage NuGet Packages -> Search "Toolkit" and select the one by Microsoft.

[image: Toolkit]

Add the namespace to your XAML and you're ready to go.

```XAML
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit">
```

[The Windows Phone Toolkit's CodePlex Project Page](http://phone.codeplex.com/)

---

List of All Toolkit Control's in the Toolbox

[image]

Comment: I did what you said, but I still get the standard controls, there's nothing new

Comment: There should be over 30 new controls in the toolkit.  It won't get added to the Toolbox automatically, you have to add it yourself by browsing to the .dll file.  Type in the above namespace to use the library in your xaml, then type in `<toolkit:`  and you will see all of the controls because of intellisense.  I updated the solution to show a list of controls once it is added to the Toolbox correctly.

Comment: If you want some web style toolkit which those generic looking things, then there are other toolkits you can download using NuGet.

Comment: sorry for being so slow, but I finally got it right. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where can I find the .dll file for Windows Phone Toolkit?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, at this time you can't mix Silverlight and WinRT controls. And I doubt it will ever be possible, as Microsoft is likely to move towards ditching Silverlight.