# toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm designing a xaml page, if I do not insert toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" my page has an "invalid XAML". 
Here's the complete page:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="SolLongListSelector_WinPhone8.Page1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"

    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->


        <!-- Slide Show with Pivot Control -->
        <controls:Pivot
                Grid.Row="0" 
                Grid.Column="0"
                Name="slide_show" 
                Margin="0,-100,0,0"
                SelectionChanged="slide_show_SelectionChanged">

            <!-- Pivot item template -->
            <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image  Name="img" 
                            CacheMode="BitmapCache" 
                            Source="{Binding image}" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                            Stretch="Uniform" 
                            toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
                             />
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot>


    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

I want to take off the TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled but I can't! Also keeping it gives me an error: 
Error   10  The name "TiltEffect" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit".

Any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: Like Eric said, you probably forgot to add it as a reference.  I have step by step instructions to get it by using NuGet here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703114/windows-phone-8-1-silverlight-and-xaml/25705317?noredirect=1#comment40560052_25705317

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Tilt_Effect_for_Windows_Phone) installed. The TiltEffect is not a part of the Windows Phone SDK. This is most likely why you are getting those errors.

Answer (score 0):

Go to View->Other Windows->Package Manager Console , type the following command and hit enter.

> Install-Package WPtoolkit

It installs the updated Windows Phone Toolkit and it works fine.

Comment: Already installed!

PM> Install-Package WPtoolkit
'WPtoolkit 4.2013.08.16' already installed.
SolLongListSelector_WinPhone8 already has a reference to 'WPtoolkit 4.2013.08.16'.

Comment: IF that's not working for, I can give you alternate solution. Just add this TileEffect.cs in this link https://github.com/BalasubramaniM/HelperClass/blob/master/TiltEffect.cs , change the namespace with your project name and build the project. Add reference, xmlns:local="clr-namespace:[Namespace]" and use the control as, local:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True". Hope it helps you.