# Windows Phone 8.1 (Silverlight) message box extended functionality

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, custom-controls, messagebox

I want to create a messag box in Windows Phone 8.1 (Silverlight) with extended functionality, not just a title, message and Ok/cancel buttons.

My question is how do I create a message box that can show this kind of functionality as shown in my rough sketch:

[image: Custom message box]

Is this possible in Windows Phone 8.1?

**EDIT:**
Does the [Windows Phone Toolkit's](https://phone.codeplex.com/) CustomMessageBox match my needs?

Comment: Yes CustomMessageBox will match your need, but I am not sure whether you can add a Windows Phone Toolkit in the project for WP8.1. If yes, then I gurantee that it will meet your requirements.

Comment: I guess "Install-Package : Unable to find package 'WPtoolkit'." when istalling it with NuGet means that I can't add the Windows Phone Toolkit in my 8.1 project @KinjanBhavsar

So I guess my other option is to create a new page that can work as an "options page" perhaps?

Comment: Try WP8Toolkit keyword in Nuget

Comment: PM> Install-Package WP8Toolkit GIVE ME THE MESSAGE: Install-Package : Unable to find package 'WP8Toolkit'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package WP8Toolkit
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: Ok is ContentDialog available?

Comment: No I can't seem to add a ContentDialog to my Silverlight project for Windows Phone 8.1 @KinjanBhavsar

Comment: Then new page is the quick option to progress with your work. :-(

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703114/windows-phone-8-1-silverlight-and-xaml. And try to search in Nuget Package Manager. Don't try to install it directly

Comment: It worked @KinjanBhavsar ! Can you post that comment as an answer so I can accept it as an answer to my question?

Comment: Great. Please tick my answer as correct. I have added same comment in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [Content Dialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.aspx) class. In that you can anything you want. Its similar to CustomMessageBox.

**Update (For Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight)**

Check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703114/windows-phone-8-1-silverlight-and-xaml) And try to search in Nuget Package Manager. Don't try to install it directly

Comment: Is it available in the Silverlight for Windows Phone 8.1 @KinjanBhavsar can't seem to implement it in my project

Comment: Please check this also. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Coding4Fun-Toolkit-bc454114